# Getting x, y, slope in raster, using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, slope

I'm the new to QGIS.

I have a slope raster that was made by using DEM 5m (also that was made by using contour 5m shp file).

How do I get a txt(or csv ...) file containing [x, y, slope] data?

I used 'gdal2xyz', 'raster-translate' but I couldn't get slope data.

Also, they were formed [x, y, z] and z is always '-9999'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the algorithm `Raster Values to points` (or `Raster Pixels to points` [Documentation link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#raster-pixels-to-points)). Once the point layer is created you could export it as a csv file :)

[image: QGIS Raster values to points processing tool]